# Why is extracting tar archive in Docker container so slow on Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

When running the following command in PowerShell on my computer, the process finishes in about 10 minutes.

```bsh
Measure-Command { 7z x -aoa qt-everywhere-src-5.14.2.tar | Out-Default }
```

When running it inside a docker container, it takes more than 2 hours!

The `tar` file is in a mounted volume (and is extracted to the same mounted volume). I have added the mounted folder to the exclusion list of both Windows Defender and Windows Indexing.

I'm running Docker Desktop version 2.2.0.5 with Windows containers on my Windows 10 computer. I'm using the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` with Chocolatey and 7-zip installed in the container.

The file I'm extracting can be downloaded from here: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.14/5.14.2/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.14.2.tar.xz (the `tar`-file inside the `xz`-file)

Comment: I don't know why people are still surprised that a) MS is slow and bloated and, b) docker (a Linux technology) doesn't work very well in windows.

Comment: a) If the issue is that MS is slow and bloated, as you claim, shouldn't that slow down the command on the host system also, and not only in the container? b) Do you have any documentation that Docker should not work well on Windows. If being a "Linux technology" makes it inadequate for Windows, why would they make a Windows version?

Comment: Same problem here, it is also valid case in docker ee and it is slower than extracting tar in a linux vm in the same windows machine.